# Postgres 'copy' to csv sql construction works fine with pgAdmin but produces empty csv-files in psql

Tags: postgresql, copy, psql

I have an sql-script like:
copy(select...) to...

It works absolutely fine when i run it through pgAdmin.

But the same script results in empty csv in case I try to run it in psql:

```
psql -U a_user -d dbv -a -f script.sql
```

I use the same db, user, script. There should not be a problem with access: the file is created, but empty...

Does anybody face the same?

Comment: Have you looked at the logs? there you might find what's going on.

Comment: I would check whether schema paths are the same.

Comment: you don't have -h key for psql - you run it on server's socket ?.. if you run select without copy - there are rows?..

Comment: Looks I've found the problem. When I run the script via pgAdmin it uses UTF-8 encoding, but for cli doesn't.

Comment: So "SET PGCLIENTENCODING=utf-8" in the script removes my headache :)